# Primeface Tooltip should look like rowEditor Tooltip

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip

I am using a primeface dataTable and the primeface rowEditor. As tooltip for the deleteLink I use a primeface tooltip.
The primeface tooltip doesn´t look like the rowEditor tooltip. Is there a possibility that they look same?

```
                <p:column style="width:32px">
                    <p:rowEditor editTitle="Bearbeiten" saveTitle="Speichern" cancelTitle="Abbrechen" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:32px">
                    <p:commandLink id="deleteLink" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" action="#{SFKBean.deleteStrasse(str)}" update="strList, :sdform:msgs" />
                    <p:tooltip id="deleteLinkTT" for="deleteLink" value="Straße entfernen" position="bottom" />
                </p:column>
```

[That's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4GlC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowEditor` '...title' tooltips are browser tooltips. `p:tooltip` generates non-browser tooltips that (can by design) are not easily made to look like browser tooltips (different for each browser) and are meant for components that doe not support browser based tooltips. If you want a 'normal' tooltip, use the `title` attribute on the `p:commandLink`

```
<p:commandLink id="deleteLink" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" action="#{SFKBean.deleteStrasse(str)}" update="strList, :sdform:msgs" title="Straße entfernen" />
```

If you **do** want to style the `p:tooltip` like browser native ones, add a `styleClass` attribute to it and make selectors that are specific for browsers (might require some javascript)

Comment: I doesn´t see that there is a title Attribute. This does what I want. Thank you!

Comment: there is in the documentation: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/commandlink